# Dictionary missing key(s) when method returns it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have some code that performs modified BFS on a graph that I have created and stores some path information at every node. After the BFS run finishes, my code packages the path list and returns it. Here is the control flow:

```
Executable->BFS(graph)->Package_Path_List(node)
```

This is the `package_path_list` method:

```
def package_path_list(self, end):
    '''Packages the path list at the destination node
    This method packages the path list for user display and returns the optimal
    paths present at the destination node
    '''
    final_path_list = {}
    dest_id = handler.TOPOLOGY_GRAPH.get_vertex(end.get_id())
    for key, value in end.nodePathTable.items():
        path = list(key)
        # Append the destination’s ID to the end of each path
        final_path_list[(path.append(dest_id))] = value
        pfLogger.debug("Packaging path list: " + str(path) + ":" + str(value))
    return (final_path_list)
```

Which is called by the `hfs_pathfinder` method:

```
testDict = dict(self.package_path_list(end))
pfLogger.debug("Returned Path List: " + str(testDict))
return(testDict)
```

The problem is that my log files show that the dict is created and exists fine in the `package_path_list` method, and the logs for the `bfs_pathfinder` method show me the value correctly, but the key is showing up as `None`.

Here are the logs:

```
pathfinding:DEBUG:bfspathfinder:345:  Packaging path list: [1 connectedTo: ['2', '4'], 2    
connectedTo: ['1', '3'], 3 connectedTo: ['2', '4']]:[1536.0, 6.0, 18.0]

pathfinding:DEBUG:bfspathfinder:295:  Returned Path List: {None: [1536.0, 6.0, 18.0]}
```

I don’t see any wrong reference assignments here. Could someone please point out the mistake? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    final_path_list[(path.append(dest_id))] = value
```

When you `append` to a list, it happens in-place and will `return None`, *not* the list. You need to make this two steps:

```
path.append(dest_id)
final_path_list[tuple(path)] = value
```

Note that I turn `path` into a tuple: lists are mutable, so can't be dictionary keys.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that. I wasn’t aware of the in-place behavior of lists. I was cracking my head on this for a good hour. Appreciate the help. :)